# Запятая после прямой речи

Tags: запятые, прямая-речь, цитата

Нужна ли эта запятая?

1. Я думаю, что вопрос «Как дела?»(,) часто-таки задаваемый, – это супернеинтересный вопрос.

А в этом случае?

2. Я думаю, что этот вопрос: «Как дела?»(,) – часто-таки задаваемый, – это супернеинтересный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Прямая речь как член предложения, далее **запятая** перед обособленным оборотом.

*Я думаю, что вопрос **«Как дела?»,** часто-таки задаваемый, – это супернеинтересный вопрос.*

(2) Прямая речь находится внутри слов автора, на месте разрыва была **запятая**, а прямая речь **вопросительная** (ставится тире):

*Я думаю, что этот вопрос: **«Как дела?»** – часто-таки задаваемый, – это супернеинтересный вопрос.*

**Сравнить** (предложение без прямой речи): *Я думаю, что этот вопрос, часто-таки задаваемый, – это супернеинтересный вопрос.*

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159) § 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора.

Если прямая речь находится **внутри слов автора**, то перед ней ставится двоеточие, а после нее — или запятая, или тире, или запятая и тире (по условиям контекста).

**Обобщение правила:**

(1) Если на месте разрыва слов автора стоит **запятая,** но прямая речь **не является повествовательной,** то после прямой речи ставится **тире** (но не запятая).

(2) Если  прямая речь повествовательная, то **запятая** сохраняется.

(3) Если на месте разрыва не было знаков, то тоже ставится **тире**: *Я думаю, что этот вопрос: «Как дела» – есть супернеинтересный вопрос, да и не вопрос вовсе.*

**Примеры:**

*И не грозился снег: «Вот стаю!» – а под ногами всё крепчал.*

*Мама всегда говорит: «Прекрасно!» – а потом пишет на другой стороне рисунка свои статьи.*

*Когда пешеход спросил у Эзопа: «Сколько часов ходьбы до Афин?» – мудрец не сразу смог ему ответить.*

Comment: Да не нужно тут ничего обобщать, *Sharon*. Если прямая речь заканчивается вопросительным знаком, то после нее всегда ставится тире. Вы дважды ошиблись и дважды поменяли свое решение. И — заметьте! — никто Вас не "минуснул".

Comment: Римма, спасибо за напоминание, я работаю над своим ответом, а ошибки мои считать не надо. Я сама с ними разберусь, а ответ могу и пять раз поменять.  Можете хоть сейчас минус поставить, если вас это утешит.  У меня свои источники, по которым я даю ответ или исправляю его.  И у нас здесь не соревнование: кто быстрее галочку получит.  Хочется правильно ответить на интересный вопрос. А что вы хотите,  не знаю, хотя можно догадаться.

Comment: Ну зачем же Вы так? Если бы ваше первое решение было правильным, я бы его с удовольствием оценила, а сама бы уже не стала отвечать.

Comment: Не надо меня КОНТРОЛИРОВАТЬ,  занимайтесь своими ответами, отвечайте или не отвечайте – мне дела нет,  а вам вот есть. Все успваете: и ответить, и мои ошибки посчитать, и вот комментарии мне пишете. А зачем? Критика, и довольно злая. Не по правилам форума.

Comment: О господи, чем же злая-то?.. Всех благ Вам, *Sharon*!

Comment: А по ответу: зачем первое тире в первом варианте, перед причастным оборотом?

Comment: Не помню. Если неправильно, поставьте минус.

Comment: "Злодеев нет вовсе на свете. Мы все простодушны, как дети. Задиры и врушки, Мы всё делим игрушки,.."  Не поделили.  Драка в песочнице, а ведь взрослые люди.

Comment: А первое тире я случайно поставила не там, где хотела.

Comment: А почему Вы думаете, что большая таки нужна буква?

Comment: У Розенталя написано – и даже дан пример, – что возможно также иногда тире и запятую ставить. У Лопатина этого, однако, нет (про и тире и запятую). Это упоминание о постановке тире и запятой, сделанное Розенталём, уже нерелевантно, что ли?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Я отвечу вам в поле ответа.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** *Я думаю, что вопрос «**к**ак дела?», часто-таки задаваемый, — это супернеинтересный вопрос.*

Лопатин:

> [**§ 143.**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137) Цитата, включенная в авторское предложение на правах его компонента, выделяется кавычками (но начинается со строчной буквы), знаки препинания употребляются только те, которые диктуются самим авторским предложением...

*«как дела?»* — член предложения (я бы по рекомендации Лопатина написала со строчной буквы); перед причастным оборотом, конечно же, нужна запятая.

**2.** *Я думаю, что этот вопрос: **«Как дела?» —** часто-таки задаваемый, — это супернеинтересный вопрос.*

> § 136. Если прямая речь оказывается внутри слов автора, то она заключается в кавычки, а перед ней ставится двоеточие; прямая речь начинается с прописной буквы. После прямой речи знаки препинания расставляются следующим образом: <...>
> в) тире ставится, если прямая речь заканчивается многоточием, вопросительным или восклицательным знаком... *Я повторяю: «Что сказано?» — и держу ее долго на стойке* (Пришв.)...

Запятая после "Как дела?" **не ставится**, только тире, так как прямая речь заканчивается вопросительным знаком.
Но тогда причастный оборот *часто-таки задаваемый* оказывается обрамленным двумя тире.
Написала бы так:
*Я думаю, что этот вопрос: «Как дела?» — это супернеинтересный вопрос, часто-таки задаваемый.*

Comment: Оборот тесно примыкает по смыслу к вопросу, поэтому не надо тире.

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ (дополнительная информация по комментариям)

**Разное оформление дословных высказываний** (в том числе о выборе прописной или строчной буквы)

1. Оформление дословного высказывания  возможно различным образом, это выбор автора по тексту. При этом надо учитывать, что **наибольшая выделительная способность**  у классической прямой речи. В то же время существуют различные **переходные варианты** - упрощенная различными способами  прямая речь, а также косвенная речь. При упрощении прямой речи пропускается тире, двоеточие, а также используется **строчная буква место прописной.**
2. **Произношение** при этом тоже учитывается. Если важно подчеркнуть предупредительную паузу, то даже короткую запись можно оформить как прямую речь и поставить двоеточие.
3. **Можно сравнить такие варианты:**

С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.

Предположение дневального, что «взводный нажрался и дрыхнет где-то в избе», всё больше собирало сторонников.

На вопрос «Чьи это луга?» ему никто не мог толком ответить.

Вдруг раздалось громкое «Ура!»

Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича .

Он вскочил, но она воскликнула «сидите, играйте!» и опять исчезла.

Я только посмотрел на неё, а она отвернулась и, сказавши «ступайте за мной, мой паж », пошла к флигелю.

**Розенталь и Лопатин (о репликах разных лиц: запятая и тире или запятая)**

**Розенталь:** реплики разных лиц, первая реплика повествовательная

3. Когда приказчик говорил: «Хорошо бы, барин, то и то сделать», — «Да, недурно», — отвечал он обыкновенно. (Г.);
   Когда приходил к нему мужик и, почесавши рукою затылок, говорил: «Барин, позволь отлучиться на работу, подать заработать», — «Ступай», — говорил он (Г.) — **запятая и тире** разделяют две реплики разных лиц, находящиеся внутри слов автора.

**Лопатин:** две реплики разных лиц  с дополнением (первая реплика повествовательная, а также восклицательная или вопросительная)

г) **запятая и тире** ставятся между репликами, принадлежащими разным лицам, но объединенными общим авторским предложением: Когда приказчик говорил: «Хорошо бы, барин, то и то сделать», — «Да, недурно», — отвечал он обыкновенно (Г.);

если же в первой реплике имеются **знаки** восклицательный или вопросительный, **запятая опускается:** Когда я спросила: «Почему вы носите на спине ковер?» — «Мне холодно», — ответил он; то же при ином расположении частей авторского пред- ложения: Когда я спросила: «Почему вы носите на спине ковер?» — он ответил: «Мне холодно» (Ток.).

Comment: Вы хорошее правило привели. По условиям контекста... Не надо здесь формализма. В контексте оборот, который тесно примыкает к вопросу. Тире не подходит. Тире разделяет.

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае запятая нужна в силу правила обособления причастного оборота.

Второй случай осложнён оформлением прямой речи. По общему правилу оформления прямой речи запятая не нужна, но она снова нужна по правилу обособления причастного оборота. Он никуда не делся и требует сохранения своих знаков препинания. Тире там стоит по другому поводу и никак на обособление причастного оборота не влияет.

Comment: М-м... Здесь нет деепричастного оборота.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил